# smtplib doesn't send mail

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I wrote this script for sending email to phones using SMTP protocol and GMail services. But It doesn't work because when the message is sended, the recipient is null. Why? Where are the problem?

Python code:

```
import smtplib
import os 
import time
import sys
import argparse
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


class smsGatewaying:


    def login_gmail(self,user,password):
        debuglevel = 0

        self.server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        self.server.starttls()
        self.server.set_debuglevel(False)

        self.gmail_user = args.gmail_user
        gmail_password = args.gmail_password

        if len(gmail_password) < 1:
                print 'Insert a password!'
                gmail_password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Insert the GMail password: ")
        else:

                self.server.login(self.gmail_user, gmail_password)
                print 'Login successfully.'
                time.sleep(0.75)
                sms.select_country()


    def select_country(self):
        print 'Insert country: '
        country = raw_input()

        ################# COUNTRY #################

        if country == 'Italy' or country == 'italy':

            ################# CARRIERS #################


            italian_carriers = ['number@sms.vodafone.it',
                                '39number@timnet.com'] #0 VODAFONE 1 TIM

            select_carriers = raw_input("Select carriers: ")

            if select_carriers == 'Vodafone' or select_carriers == 'vodafone':
                number = 0
            elif select_carriers == 'TIM' or select_carriers == 'tim' or select_carriers == 'Tim':
                number = 1
            else:
                print "L'operatore telefonico selezionato non è disponibile."
                time.sleep(0.80)
                sms.select_country()



            sms.send_message_normal(italian_carriers[number])

        else:
            sys.exit()



    def send_message_normal(self, carriers):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['telephone'] = input("Insert telephone number: ")
        text = raw_input("Insert text: ")
        msg.attach = (MIMEText(text))

        sender = self.gmail_user
        to = carriers.replace('number',str(msg['telephone']))
        to_list = [to]
        print to
        print to_list

        final = raw_input("Are you sure?[Y/N] ")


        if final == 'y' or final == 'Y':

            try:

                self.server.sendmail(sender,to,text)
            except SMTPException:
                print 'Unable to send.'
                time.sleep(0.75)
                sms.select_country()


        elif final == 'n' or final == 'N':
            exit_ = raw_input("Do you want to exit?[Y/N] ")

            if exit_ == 'Y' or exit_ == 'y':

                print 'Run main script...'
                newWorkingDirectory = '../BRES.py'
                os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.path[0]), newWorkingDirectory)
                os.system('python BRES.py')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("gmail_user", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("gmail_password",type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()


    sms = smsGatewaying()
    os.system('clear')
    print 'Welcome to SMS Gatewaying service! Multiple countries and multiple carriers are available.'
    print ''
    time.sleep(1)
    sms.login_gmail(args.gmail_user,args.gmail_password)
```